# how do I write a formula where the number portion of a cell reference comes from another cell?

Tags: excel

In cell G14 I have the formula `=MAX(D2:D14)`

I plan to copy this formula to all the cells in the column G. But, the formula needs to vary so that it is not always working against a fixed range.

What I want is something like:
`=MAX(D2:D(H14))`
That would pull the number portion of the cell address from the cell to the right.

Answer (score 4):

To work against the volatile behavior of `INDIRECT` most of the times solutions using `INDEX` are also possible. So here too.

```
=MAX(D2:INDEX(D:D,H14))
```

About [volatile behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx):
Excel supports the concept of a volatile function, that is, one whose value cannot be assumed to be the same from one moment to the next even if none of its arguments (if it takes any) has changed. Excel reevaluates cells that contain volatile functions, together with all dependents, every time that it recalculates. For this reason, too much reliance on volatile functions can make recalculation times slow. Use them sparingly.

Comment: This is by far the better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

`=MAX(INDIRECT("D2:D" & H14))` will do it, assuming `H14` contains the number.

But do note that using `INDIRECT` makes the workbook *volatile*.