# how to specify a range of array from numbers in other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array 1 to 7 listed from A1 to A7. The numbers 1 and 7 are listed in B1 and C1.

I would like to calculate the sum (=SUM(A1:A7)) in the array, but the range of the array needs to be specified from other cells (=SUM(A$**B1**:A$**C1**)).

What is the right way to express the desired formula (=SUM(A$**B1**:A$**C1**))?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845752/how-do-i-write-a-formula-where-the-number-portion-of-a-cell-reference-comes-from/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INDIRECT function.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&C1))
```

This came from  [The INDIRECT Function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

link: [Answer in sheet array](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=CONCATENATE("=SUM(A",B1,":A",C1,")")
```

copy that formula in other cell, then paste special the result into the other cell, and then change the decimal format.